# My model has a second model inside of it

Tags: modeling, pose-mode

When I try posing my model, it appears to have another model on the inside, and I have no idea how to delete it...

If you need more screen caps or data just let me know.

[image]

Comment: probably there is a duplicate mesh, you need to go in Edit mode and delete it, if it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In edit mode, what prompt do I use to delete it? There's an option that says "Remove doubles" but that didn't change anything. As an experiment, I selected a bunch of faces. Hit delete. Nothing was gone. Did it again, and the faces left. So there is in fact two models on top of one another. but when I selected everything with  ctrl left mouse click, it deletes all of the model.

Comment: maybe use L to select one of the 2 meshes (if there are 2)

Comment: Isn't it a ghost?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6417" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6417/)  here's a download link if you want to find a solution. I do have a backup file. I'll just lose a few hours of work.

Comment: Okay, it took some effort, but I got the meshes separated and it's working like usual again. Thanks for the help.